# Простой пример использования Foreground service

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, связанное с передачей геолокации, написанное под Андроид(java) и проблема состоит в том, что при сворачивании или блокировке экрана передача геоданных прерывается. Решил, что использование сервиса foreground может решить проблему. Как можно реализовать этот сервис на простом примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если будете работать с местоположением, вам необходимо разрешение android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION Это новое разрешение для доступа к местоположению в фоне.

Показываю вам пример кода, которые можно использовать. Для инъекции используется dagger 2.28.3

```kotlin
class EventRecorderService : LifecycleService() {

  // тут все ваши зависимости, обычно это livedata которая поставляет какие-то данные, например местоположение.

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        // подписываетесь и обрабатываете результат вашей livedata
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // создание того самого висящего в шторке оповещения
        val notification = NotificationHelper.trackingNotification(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0L))
            .build()
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

        if (intent.action == null) {
            Timber.e("action was null, flags = $flags +  bits = ${Integer.toBinaryString(flags)}")
            return START_STICKY
        }

        when (intent.action) {
            KEY_START -> startTracking()
            KEY_STOP -> stopTracking()
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

private fun stopTracking() {
        // пример оставновки сервиса
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }

companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        private const val KEY_START = "START"
        private const val KEY_STOP = "STOP"

        fun start(context: Context) {
            sendAction(context, KEY_START)
        }

        fun stop(context: Context) {
            sendAction(context, KEY_STOP)
        }

        private fun sendAction(context: Context, action: String) {
            val intent = Intent(context, EventRecorderService::class.java)
            intent.action = action
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
        }

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        fun isRunning(context: Context): Boolean {
        // это проверка запущен ли сервис, могут быть отключены оповещения для вашего приложения, это нужно проверять
            val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (EventRecorderService::class.java.name == service.service.className) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        @WorkerThread
        fun autoLaunchService(context: Context) {
            // тут некая логика запуска, которая решит стартовать сервис или нет
            start(context)
    }
}
```